# You're calling `removeAnnotationIcon` after the `MapView` was destroyed, were you invoking it after `onDestroy()`? mapbox

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mapbox, marker

[You're calling `removeAnnotationIcon` after the `MapView` was destroyed, were you invoking it after `onDestroy()`?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOv77.png)

this a ambildata function

```
 for (i in p0.children) {
                    var user: ModelSharing? =
                        i.getValue(ModelSharing::class.java)
                    var datalongitude = user!!.longitude
                    var datalatitude = user.latidude
                    var nama = user.name
                    var foto = user.image
                    lokasi = LatLng(datalatitude, datalongitude)
                        if (markerViewManager != null) {
                            customview = LayoutInflater.from(context!!.applicationContext)
                                .inflate(R.layout.marker, null)
                            customview.layoutParams =
                                FrameLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
                            val titleTextView: TextView =
                                customview.findViewById(R.id.marker_window_title)
                            val gambarView: ImageView =
                                customview.findViewById(R.id.gambarview)

                            Picasso.get().load(foto).resize(50,50)
                                .into(gambarView)
                            marker = MarkerView(lokasi, customview)
                            titleTextView.text = nama
                            markerViewManager?.addMarker(marker)
                            markerMap.put(counter, marker)
                            counter++
                            //break
                        }
                }
```

this is a onMapReady

```
override fun onMapReady(mapboxMap: MapboxMap) {
        this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap

        mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS) {

            enableLocationComponent(it)
            markerViewManager = MarkerViewManager(mapboxfamily, mapboxMap)
            mapboxMap.addOnMapClickListener(this)
            if (setMarker == true)
            {
                try {
                    ambildata()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

            }
        }


    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYU1z.png)

1. each fragment moves and returns to the previous fragment. it will bug. how to handle it?

Comment: Could you give more information, like how and when you're calling the code in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, to prevent it, try to override the `onDestroy` and not `onDestroyView`.

```
   override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()

    mapBox.locationComponent.isLocationComponentEnabled = false
    mapView.onDestroy()
}
```

Comment: i use fragment 
this is my code
``` 
override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()

        if (locationEngine != null) {
            locationEngine!!.removeLocationUpdates(callback)
        }
        markerViewManager!!.onDestroy()
        mapboxfamily.onDestroy()

    }```

Comment: Don't use `onDestroyView`, you need to set `isLocationComponentEnabled = false` before calling `mapView.onDestroy()`